# Setting a variable to change format of a cell

Tags: vba, excel, variables

I made this macro a while ago, and it seemed to work, but now it doesn't.

Its now saying that cell E26 is empty, but in fact it has GBP in the cell.

The Range("G9") etc has numbers is which i want to add a £ sign when cell E26 has GBP in it.

```
Dim E26

If E26 = "GBP" Then
    Range("G9:G22:G24:G26").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"    
ElseIf E26 = "EUR" Then
    Range("G9:G22:G24:G26").NumberFormat = "[$€-2] #,##0.00"    
ElseIf E26 = "USD" Then
    Range("G9:G22:G24:G26").NumberFormat = "[$$-409]#,##0.00"    
End If
```

Comment: Do you have an error? If yes, what is the message and what is the line? If no, what isn't going as expected?

Comment: The only items ive changed since last time it worked, is the cell its was G16 last time. It doesnt come up with an error, as it doesnt highlight a line of code. When I hover over E26 on the second line of code, is says that its empty. But in excel the cell contains GBP. Not sure if i need to change "Dim E26" to something else.

Comment: @JJunior is `GBP` part of the Cell formatting done in Excel ?

Comment: You know that this: `Range("G9:G22:G24:G26")` is the same as this: `Range("G9:G26")`? Or did you mean: `Range("G9:G22,G24:G26")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`E26` variable was empty because you didn't fill it, you'd have needed something like `E26 = ...`!

I changed the name of the variable to `E26val` so that you see the difference :

```
Dim E26val As String

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    E26val = .Range("E26").Value
    With .Range("G9:G22:G24:G26")
        Select Case E26val
            Case Is = "GBP"
                .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
            Case Is = "EUR"
                .NumberFormat = "[$€-2] #,##0.00"
            Case Is = "USD"
                .NumberFormat = "[$$-409]#,##0.00"
            Case Else
                'Nothing
        End Select 'E26val
    End With '.Range("G9:G22:G24:G26")
End With 'Sheets("Sheet1")
```

I also added the reference to a sheet so that it'll know on which sheet to work :

Change `Sheet1` in `With Sheets("Sheet1")` to the name of your sheet or to `With ActiveSheet` if you want it to work the active sheet! ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado : Thx! I'm forcing myself to take that habit because of nested with and stuff (working with Word at the moment, so it's pretty damn usefull!^^)

Comment: @JJunior : Glad I could help! ;) Remember to accept an answer that solved your issue! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Better to allways fully qualify your `Range`.

Also, your code is "screaming" for `Select Case`.

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CurrencyUsed()

' modify "Sheet1" with your sheet's name  
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G9:G22:G24:G26")

    Select Case Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E26").Value
        Case "GBP"
            .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
        Case "EUR"
            .NumberFormat = "[$€-2] #,##0.00"
        Case "USD"
            .NumberFormat = "[$$-409]#,##0.00"

    End Select
End With

End Sub
```